# Getting error while compiling PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, syntax-error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
   RETURN VARCHAR(20);
 IS 
   e_name VARCHAR(20); 
 BEGIN 
    SELECT emp_name INTO e_name
    FROM employees WHERE emp_no = '5';
    RETURN e_name;
 END employer_details_func;
```

While compiling the above program I'm getting this error

> Error(2,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using
>   external character    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined
>   aggregate    result_cache

**UPDATE**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
   RETURN VARCHAR2(20);
 IS 
   e_name VARCHAR2(20); 
 BEGIN 
    SELECT emp_name INTO e_name FROM employees WHERE emp_no ='5';
    RETURN e_name;
 END employer_details_func;
```

**Error**:

```
Error(2,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache
```

What is wrong with my code? Please let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using VARCHAR2?

Comment: Data type of parameters, or returning data type of a function should be unconstrained data types. That is you do need to specify maximum size. In your case `return varchar(20)` should be simply `return varchar2`. Do not use `varchar` data type. Although `varchar` and `varchar2` are synonymous and there is no difference between them right now, their behavior may change in the future - stick to `varchar2`. Moreover take into consideration the fact that your query may return no rows, or return more than one row, raising `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` exception respectively.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov I'm changed but still error persisting me

Comment: What exactly have you changed? Post updated version of your code with corresponding error message. It's also very likely that your left semicolon after `return ... ` - remove it. Otherwise your function should compile just fine.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov see my update version and error

Comment: I removed semicolon but still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RETURN VARCHAR` instead of `RETURN VARCHAR(20);`.

Oracle documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm says *RETURN Clause ... The datatype cannot specify a length, precision, or scale ...*

---

**Edit**

I double checked it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ccda5/1) with this code and it seems to work (returns bob):

```
CREATE TABLE employees(emp_name VARCHAR2(20), emp_no VARCHAR2(20))
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
   RETURN VARCHAR
 IS 
   e_name VARCHAR(20); 
 BEGIN 
   SELECT emp_name INTO e_name FROM employees WHERE emp_no ='5';
   RETURN e_name;
 END employer_details_func;
/

insert into employees values('bob','5');
select employer_details_func() from dual;
```

Comment: What is the major difference between varchar and varchar2?

Comment: Currently, there is no difference. But according to http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types this may change in the future. So using VARCHAR you risk unexepected implications when migrating to future versions of ORACLE database.

Comment: It works on SQL Fiddle (see edit). What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: ya working but what is the difference between return varchar2(20) and return varchar2?

Comment: The difference is, that varchar2(20) means, your varchar2 can have a maximum length of 20 BYTES or CHARS and without the (20) it's not restricted. In the definition of the return value of a function you can't restrict the maximum length. Oracle does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
   RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS 
   e_name VARCHAR2(20); 
 BEGIN 
    SELECT emp_name INTO e_name FROM employees WHERE emp_no ='5';
    RETURN e_name;
 END employer_details_func;
```

Comment: it's works fine but what is the difference between `return varchar2(20)` and `return varchar2`?

Comment: For that check the answer of @halfbit below. It's per definition by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE

FUNCTION employer_details_func

RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

e_name VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

```
SELECT last_name INTO e_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id ='100';

RETURN e_name;
```

END employer_details_func;

You cannot mention the size of the return type its managed by oracle engine.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func

RETURN employees.e_name%TYPE

IS

e_name employees.e_name%TYPE;

BEGIN

```
SELECT emp_name INTO e_name FROM employees WHERE emp_no ='5';

RETURN e_name;
```

END employer_details_func;